# ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (6,) (12,)

Tags: python, numpy, matrix

For a list of arrays, I wrote a simple code. Let say that
A=[[1,2,3,4,5,6], [7,8,9,10,11,12], [2,5,6,7,8,1], [3,3,3,3,3,3]].
I want to write a function that for a simple function f(X,Y)=X+Y where X, Y are arrays of A, provide the inverse.
function should take Q and predict X and Y for it. To do it, I wrote a function that for each query array Q, it start to compute all f(A[i],A[j]) and then compute |f(A[i],A[j])-Q| and create a 4*4 of these differences. My problem is that my function does not work and get error.

```
d=np.full((4, 4), np.inf)
def prediction(Q):
    for i in range(4):
        for j in np.arange(i, 4):
            o= np.asarray(A[i])*1.2+np.asarray(A[j])                   
            d[i,j]= np.linalg.norm(np.asarray(o)-np.asarray(Q))
    return d
```

I defined c as: c=A[1]+A[3]
and error I get is:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-120-456401dffe19> in <module>
----> 1 prediction(c)

<ipython-input-117-8b76ff003549> in prediction(Q)
      4         for j in np.arange(i, 4):
      5             o= np.asarray(A[i])*1.2+np.asarray(A[j])
----> 6             d[i,j]= np.linalg.norm(np.asarray(o)-np.asarray(Q))
      7     return d

ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (6,) (12,)
```

why is this happening?

Comment: do you know why the `o` and `Q` arrays have the shapes reported in the error?

Comment: no. they both should have same  size 6

Comment: Why did you delete your identical previous question to repost it? And, as previously requested: **what is the exact expected output given the provided `A`**?

Comment: Because my question was unclear there. Now, I made it more clear

Comment: my expected output is a 4*4 matrix for any input. this matrix shows the difference between f( A[i] ,A[j] ) for each i,j in range 4 and the query point.

Comment: You could have edited the question to clarify it. Please provide the requested expected output as a numpy array (else the question is too unclear and should be closed).

Comment: Ok. more explanation. I wrote a network that approximate two outputs for one input. Say taking Z as input, it gives back X and Y that created Z (Z=X+Y here). My network here has come to an approximation of f(X,Y)= 1.2X+Y as I wrote in my function. Now, for a given Z, I want to compute all possible f(X,Y) to see which one is more closer to Z. So, I put all |f(X,Y)-Z| for all possible set of ( X,Y) where X,Y \in A here, to a matrix and then find argmin for it. But I can not create this matrix because I get error. And I do not know why. Because my code seems flawless to me.

Comment: And, what is the explicit expected output matrix with `A=[[1,2,3,4,5,6], [7,8,9,10,11,12], [2,5,6,7,8,1], [3,3,3,3,3,3]]` as input?

Comment: my input is for example Q= A[1]+A[2]. So, it takes the sum of two members of A. The example  provide is a toy example for you. my function should take Q and return a 4*4 matrix which minimum value of it, should be in place [1,2]. so, my function takes an array of size 1*6 and return a 4*4 matrix

Comment: Is `A` a list or numpy array? Did you LOOK at `Q`?  I'm guessing it's a 12 element `list`.  It's your responsibility to verify the shape  of all variables. Don't guess or assume.

Comment: Q has the same shape as the other one. Actually its a mystery to me because running each line separately, get no problem. But doing all together, get error